# Disabling specific keystrokes for specific users

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, keyboard

I'm looking for a tool which allows me to disable specific keystrokes on a Windows XP/7 computer, without active directory, for specific users.

For example: disabling alt + tab, but not alt + 2. Disabling the windows key completely (windows + *).

The reason for this is that the computer will be of public usage (think library), and will only run ONE program. With this, I'll try to stop any attempts to minify / close the program.

(The program itself is programmed in Java, if that matters)

I remember coming across a tool like this in the past, but I'm unable to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) will do as you wish. Remember to set the script and shortcut to readonly for the user

[A_User](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#os) will detect the current user.

This will enable/disable right click depending on the user:

```
#persistent
hotkey, RButton UP, sub_upupandaway
return

sub_upupandaway:
    if A_User = Guest
        msgbox do something different than de default here
    else
        Send {Click up right} ; do the default action
return
```